# A specific case of sexual harassment

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idioms, expressions

How can we refer to the action where a lady is a subject to the sexual harassment with a man when the man touches the lady's private organs with hand at a public area?

> - She came to me with tearful eyes and aired up some grievances about a man who had ....... her at the bus. Apparently, the bus had been packed with people and a man had tried to touch her body in the crowd and she was really upset while she is a truly shy girl and had not been able to do anything to prevent him.

Comment: Why do you not think 'assaulted' could be the right word?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea @MichaelHarvey. I don't know what a native speaker would use in this sense. If you think, it would fit here, then let me know please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...who had **sexually assaulted** her...". Or, as Daniel Roseman has suggested, **molested**.

By the way...

"Tearful eyes" means her eyes were crying. *We* cry: our eyes don't. Or you might consider "tear-filled eyes".

I've never heard "air up", but a person doesn't usually air their grievances to an *individual* but at a meeting or in public.

I think you are misusing the conjunction *[while](https://www.lexico.com/definition/while)*.

The last sentence might be better divided in two.

Btw, she's a woman, not a lady. Either that or he's a gentleman.

Comment: He’s obviously not a gentleman as proven by his action. There is very good reason not to use two words that are equally polite. Many would put “man” into quotes to indicate that this is not how a man behaves.

Comment: @gnasher729: Maybe I should have written **irony** in big letters. (I seem to recall someone advocating the use of some punctuation mark to indicate irony some years ago. Can't remember what it looked like.)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the word you are looking for is [molested](https://www.google.com/search?q=dictionary&oq=dictionary&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.1384j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=molested):

> assault or abuse (a person, especially a woman or child) sexually.